# Wrapping bootstrap-tags into Ember Component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

So, I am using bootstrap-tags from https://github.com/maxwells/bootstrap-tags.
I am trying to implement the tags into an Ember component which currently looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'input',
  classNames: null,
  value: null,
  initTagsInput() {
    const $el = this.$();
    const _this = this;
    $el.tag({
      placeholder: 'enter associated plasmids',
      beforeAddingTag: function(tag){          //here is my problem I think?
        this.set('value', tag);
      }
    })
  },

  didInsertElement() {
    this._super();
    this.initTagsInput();
  }
});
```

The problem I am having is trying to set the value, but when I check my console or ember debugger, no value is every being assigned (value is null still). It's like the beforeAddingTag never works! I am pretty new to ember so any clarity on wrapping this library will help.

Do I need to use an observable somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
this.set('value', tag);
```

To be:

```
_this.set('value', tag);
```

And

```
this.$().tag(/**/)
```

To be:

```
this.$().tags(/**/)
```

Also the examples for that library is using a `div` so we can delete:

```
tagName: 'input'
```

The placeholder is added differently in this library too:

```
placeholder: 'enter associated plasmids'
```

Should be:

```
placeholderText: 'enter associated plasmids'
```

That said we can make `this` refer to the outer context with fat arrows from ES6 and make it prettier:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: null,
  value: null,
  initTagsInput() {
    this.$().tags({
      placeholderText: 'enter associated plasmids',
      beforeAddingTag: tag => {
        this.set('value', tag);
      }
    })
  },

  didInsertElement() {
    this._super();
    this.initTagsInput();
  }
});
```

Comment: you may be right on that, although I have tried that, I think that is part of the solution. I also realized my template is empty. Is this an instance where i want to use {{yield}}?

Comment: @TylerDavis If you're using it as a block, yeah.

Comment: that is definitely a prettier solution to this, however something seems to be still not working after doing all of your changes. I definitely feel like it's on the right track. I'm double checking now to make sure I have it exactly like you put.

Comment: @TylerDavis According to the docs at https://github.com/maxwells/bootstrap-tags it's `tags()` and not `tag()`. Can you check if you're actual code is using the right one?

Comment: strange. tag() seems to generate it properly where tags() is breaking it. looking at the same documentation you are correct. they do say tags() is the correct usage...

Comment: @TylerDavis Also their examples uses a `<div>` and not `input`. https://maxwells.github.io/demo-3.html Are you sure you're not using another library? ;)

Comment: haha that's exactly what I'm checking for now. I was also looking at bootstrap-tagsinput (not to be confused with bootstrap-tags) ;)   so I think you are exactly right.

Comment: @TylerDavis Cool. Also you need to update the placeholder option name. Should work now I think.

Comment: apparently we also are using https://github.com/fdeschenes/bootstrap-tag. which seems to have been why I can use "tag()" instead of "tags()"  -_-  Thank you Kit Sunde!